# Program not writing to another file

Tags: c, tokenize

This program is supposed to take a user's input on an area code, search a separate file that has a bunch of phone numbers listed in the txt file, and a function search is supposed to test the phone number with the input area code to see if it matches. The `main` function then writes the phone numbers into a separate txt file.

I have tried to use `strstr` but I figured the best way to test it is to use `strtok` and `strcmp`, which is what I have now.

```
/* This program will search phone_numbers.txt for phone numbers. It will create a new file with unique area codes in each file.
    (Ex: 813 area codes will go into 813_phone_numbers file).
    --Brandon Yates
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int search(char *area_code, char *phone_number);
int read_line(char *str, int n);

int main() {
    char area_code[3];
    char phone_number[101];
    char *file_name;
    FILE *number_file;
    FILE *new_file;

    printf("Enter the area code: ");
    scanf("%s", &area_code);
    //area_code = &ac;
    read_line(area_code, 2);

    number_file = fopen("phone_numbers.txt", "r");
    if (number_file == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot open file.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    new_file = fopen("dest_file.txt", "a");
    if (new_file == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot open file.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    //scat = strcat(area_code, file_name);

    while (fgets(phone_number, sizeof(phone_number), number_file) != NULL && !feof(number_file) && !ferror(number_file)) {
        if (search(area_code, phone_number))
            fputs(phone_number, new_file);
    }

    fclose(number_file);
    fclose(new_file);

    printf("Output: encoded words are written to file %s", file_name);

    return 0;
}

/*
    Search function determines if a phone number in the input file
    matches the area code.

    Search function returns 1 if the phone number matches the area code
    and 0 otherwise.
*/
int search(char *area_code, char *phone_number) {
    printf("testing");
    char *pch;
    pch = strtok(phone_number, "()");
    while (pch != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(area_code, phone_number) == 0)
            return 1;
        pch = strtok(NULL, "()");
    }
    return 0;
}

int read_line(char *str, int n) {
    int ch;
    int i = 0;

    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n') {  
        if (i < n) { 
            *str++= ch;
            i++;
        }
    }
    *str = '\0';   /* terminates string */
    return i;      /* number of characters stored */
}
```

I expect the phone numbers to be written to a text file, but I end up with an empty file. What is going on?

Comment: what is your input?  you have a lot of code here.  when you debug it, which function is failing to perform as expected?

Comment: You should show a few lines of `phone_numbers.txt` and what you enter as input.

Comment: Sorry, I did not realize that I did not post which was causing the error. It actually prints all the phone numbers now, it just doesn't test to see if the area code matches in the phone number. The function that is not working properly is search() I think specifically strcmp. I am on mobile and not sure how to edit it.

Comment: `scanf` and `read_line` aren't working with well with each other; this results in `area_code` containing garbage values. Replace `scanf` and `read_line` with `fgets`.

Comment: In the USA, an area code is three digits. To store those in a string requires 4 bytes.  You’re not allocating enough space.  Where there’s one bug like that, there are usually several, if not many of them.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems in your program:

- the array `area_code` is too small: it can only accommodate strings of 0, 1 or 2 characters. Since you do not tell `scanf()` to limit the input to a maximum of 2 characters, the area code typed by the user fills the array and `scanf` modifies memory beyond the end of the array, causing undefined behavior.
- you read user input twice into the `area_code` array. The first time with `scanf()`, which may cause undefined behavior, but leaves the newline pending in standard input, and then with `read_line()` which reads the pending newline and makes `area_code` an empty string...

  Make `area_code` larger and either tell `scanf()` about the maximum number of characters to store there or just use `read_line()`:

  ```
      char area_code[10];
      ...
      if (scanf("%9s", area_code) != 1)
          return 1;
  ```
- Note also that `fgets(phone_number, sizeof(phone_number), number_file) != NULL && !feof(number_file) && !ferror(number_file)` is redundant: `fgets()` will return `NULL` on error and/or end of file, no need to perform redundant tests.
- The test in `search` is incorrect: `if (strcmp(area_code, phone_number) == 0)` you should instead compare the token with `area_code`:

  ```
      if (strcmp(area_code, pch) == 0)
  ```
- `read_line` also has a potential problem: its argument is the maximum number of characters to read, which is different from the argument to `fgets()` which is the size of the destination array. This is confusing and might cause bugs later if the function is given `sizeof area_code` for the size argument.